# I need to speed up my site and reduce the number of files calls

Tags: web, browser-cache

My webhost is aking me to speed up my site and reduce the number of files calls.
Ok let me explain a little, my website is use in 95% as a bridge between my database (in the same hosting) and my Android applications (I have around 30 that need information from my db), the information only goes one way (as now) the app calls a json string like this the one in the site:
    http://www.guiasitio.com/mantenimiento/applinks/prlinks.php
and this webpage to show in a web view as welcome message:
    http://www.guiasitio.com/movilapp/test.php
this page has some images and jquery so I think this are the ones having a lot of memory usage, they have told me to use some code to create a cache of those files in the person browser to save memory (that is a little Chinese to me since I don't understand it) can some one give me an idea and send me to a tutorial on how to get this done?. Can the webview in a Android app keep caches of this files?
All your help his highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a CDN or content delivery network would be an easy solution if it worked well for you. Essentially you are off-loading the work or storing and serving static files (mainly images and CSS files) to another server. In addition to reducing the load on your your current server, it will speed up your site because files will be served from a location closest to each site visitor.

There are many good CDN choices. [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) is one popular option, though in my optinion the prize for the easiest service to setup is [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com) ... they offer a free plan, simply fill in the details, change the DNS settings on your domain to point to CloudFlare and you will be up and running.

With some fine-tuning, you can expect to reduce the requests on your server by up to 80%

I use both Amazon and CloudFlare, with good results. I have found that the main thing to be cautious of is to carefully check all the scripts on your site and make sure they are working as expected. CloudFlare has a simple setting where you can specify the cache settings as well, so there's another detail on your list covered.

Good luck!